# Is there a CSV, XML or JSON resource for Android permissions with description, API level and protection level?

Tags: applications, permissions

I am trying to easily parse Android permissions for an application but https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/Manifest.permission makes it hard to do so. I want to check the description, API level it was introduced in (and if deprecated), and the associated protection level.

Instead, I did my own: https://gist.github.com/HackJJ/4d06eaea2c13faa87edab88e3dd43201

However I'm not comfortable with the script I needed to write on account of the Android page being using malformed HTML in dozens of places.

Could Android or Google create something like a CSV, JSON, or XML source that developers and penetration testers can easily put into their workflow? Does such a thing already exist and my Google-fu is not strong enough?